# How to intergrate TFS with Lync

Tags: tfs, lync-2013

Is there any way to integrate Microsoft TFS project with Microsoft Lync? I am looking out for this option to simplify the team collaboration tasks such as getting a notification on new build, team meeetings based on project team members in TFS, notifications of code check-in to developers on Lync, etc.

We use Microsoft Lync 2013 version and we use Visual Studio 2012 for project development work along with TFS integration in place. Project has already invested in Lync, so want to stick with Lync not looking for other options.

Answer (score 1):

The ALM Rangers VSTS Bot comes closest to what you want: https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/VSTS-Bot Unfortunately it's not (yet) available for TFS.

I would recommend upgrading TFS and VS to the latest versions. You will get a lot of out of the box notifications that you can easily relay to a chat program like Skype for Business (previously Lync), Slack or Teams.

Comment: Thanks for info - Wouter de Kort